# What is the precise number of black racial groups of Africa?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, statutory-construction

[Revisions to the Standards for the Classification of Federal Data on 
Race and Ethnicity; Notices Federal Register / Vol. 62, No. 210 / Thursday, October 30, 1997 / 
Notices](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-1997-10-30/html/97-28653.htm), Page 58789 at

> 1. Categories and Definitions

defines

> Black or African American.

as

> A person having origins in any of the black racial groups of Africa.

and

> White.

as

> A person having origins in any of the original peoples of Europe, the
>   Middle East, or North Africa.

Questions:

1. What is the precise number of "black racial groups of Africa"?
2. Does the omission of the term "racial groups of" from the definition of "White" imply that
   a) "White" is a single "racial group";
   b) "White" is not a "racial group";
   c) the term "racial groups" is inapplicable in whole or part as to the definition of "White"?
3. What is the legal distinction between the terms "racial groups of" that is used when defining "Black or African American" and "original peoples of" that is used when defining "White"?

Comment: Is there an SE site for demography? This isn't really a legal question.

Comment: @bdb484 The administrative regulation of the Office of Management and Budget are controlling as to the definition of "Black or African American" and "White" in the United States. The question is entirely a legal one as to the construction of the legal terms used in the official document which defines the legal terms "Black or African American" and "White". Which part of the question do you believe is not legal and why?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the meaning of this is more "Let's avoid a discussion about the demographics of Africa, whatever you think the groups are does not matter at all" than "We have a fully defined list of groups and if yours is not in that list then you cannot define yourself as 'Black'"

Comment: @SJuan76 Can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: The definitions are controlling in terms of how people are counted for census purposes. To the best of my knowledge, they have no bearing on any legal obligations, rights, remedies, etc.

Comment: @bdb484 The definitions and data does effect legal obligations, rights, remedies, etc., including, but not limited to "civil rights" and "voting rights". _"Since the 1960s, data on race and ethnicity have been used extensively in civil rights monitoring and enforcement covering areas such as employment, voting rights, housing
and mortgage lending, health care services, and educational opportunities."_ [Standards for the Classification of Federal
Data on Race and Ethnicity](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/fedreg_race-ethnicity.pdf)

Comment: Right, life is interdisciplinary sometimes. We also use rulers to measure doorways for ADA enforcement, but that doesn't make "how many inches in a foot" a legal question.

Comment: @bdb484 Not certain what point you are trying to make? Are you asserting that the definitions of "Black or African American" and "White" were written by the administrative agency for no purpose? The definitions are substantially different on their face as to the meaning of "Black or African American" and "White". The question is, why? If in fact the data is used for "civil rights" and "voting rights" enforcement or monitoring, the parameters of the mandate should be clearly defined.

Comment: My point is that some times questions that are not legal in nature are nonetheless relevant to a legal analysis. "How many different fingerprint patterns are possible" is a question with legal implications, but it isn't a legal question. If you want an answer to that, you go to someone with a scientific, rather than legal, background. If you want answers to questions about racial groups, you go to someone with a background in demography or anthropology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78051/discussion-between-guest271314-and-bdb484).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about law or legal process.

Comment: @Nij The administrative regulation which defines "Black or African American" and "White" contains ambiguous and unclear terms, which is evident on its face by the failure of any user to post an answer as to precisely how many "black racial groups" do or no not exist. The constitutionality of an ambiguous statute or administrative regulation is a question of law.

Comment: @Nij In fact the administrative regulation can be challenged as to the arbitrary and capricious language "black racial groups of Africa" and the _land claim_ of "origins in any of the original peoples" "North Africa" as to the definition of "White", where "North Africa" is also unclear language. Taking the legal examination of the administrative language further, the term "race" itself can be challenged as a matter of law as being arbitrary and capricious.

Comment: @Nij It can be argued that the legal fiction "race" in any law or administrative regulation whatsoever, whether that be "American Indian or Alaska Native", "Asian", "Black or African American", "Hispanic or Latino", "Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander", "White", or "some other race" being in matter of fact and law the basis of "race" discrimination, not merely "data" _"used extensively in civil rights monitoring and enforcement covering areas such as employment, voting rights, housing and mortgage lending, health care services, and educational opportunities."_

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> I am pretty sure that the meaning of this is more "Let's avoid a
>   discussion about the demographics of Africa, whatever you think the
>   groups are does not matter at all" than "We have a fully defined list
>   of groups and if yours is not in that list then you cannot define
>   yourself as 'Black'" -[@SJuan76](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/9236/sjuan76)

> There is no theory (in any discipline) of the number of black racial
>   groups in Africa, so precision or even reasonable approximation is
>   impossible. Directive 15 is not based on science, so you'd just get
>   bloviative answers ranging from 1 to 1000 (maybe more). The rationale
>   behind the wording is to exclude white South Africans and North
>   African Arab / Berber people, who are slotted elsewhere -- also to
>   exclude non-African blacks from India etc. -[@user6726](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/14781)

Answer (score -8):

### One

All people in Africa irrespective of their skin colour are part of the race known as *homo sapiens*.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The sentiment is admirable, but it does not reflect the reality in which race, however it is defined, has been a matter of concern for many people for many centuries.